# Save incoming emails in MySQL DB using Postfix

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, postfix, email

i just installed postfix and configured it kind of right, i think..

now my goal is, to accept all incoming mails, and store every single one in my mysql database, as soon as it arrives on my server.
i only need to store the body of any email, and don't need any spam filtering programs, because what my server does is just accept all mail bodies and work through those getting specific data from those..

those emails will be deleted after getting the data out of them, so dont worry about spam or anything else.

the v-server runs Ubuntu, and i have an own domain, too.
im really new with ubuntu, and all mailserver things but have been trying 3 weeks now to make it work.. nothing really worked.

just let me know how you would do it:)

Comment: For everyone that is looking for the same solution like me: http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/content/triggering-php-script-when-your-postfix-server-receives-mail this might help you, it works the way how piza explaines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a script/programm which accepts the parameters and input from postfixs [pipe](http://www.postfix.org/pipe.8.html). Then you can define this pipe as transport for all mails.